# Mysql MATCH returning 0 when LIKE returns the right amount of results?

Tags: mysql, match, sql-like

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blah
    WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST ('c')
  ) as count1,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blah 
    WHERE text LIKE '% c %'
  ) as count2
```

This returns:

```
count1 count2
0      19
```

Why is that?

Note that ft_min_word_len is set as 1 and indexes have been rebuilt. Why is it not working? :|

The field blah has strings such as "y c h g b g p q n g j f k t y u a w d v b e x c m".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, MySQL full-text search defaults to [natural language mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).  You need to use the `IN BOOLEAN MODE` keyword to switch to [boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html), which supports the `*` operator.

Second, your full-text query finds entries that contain a word (of [four or more letters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) and [not in the stopword list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)) *beginning* with the letter `c`.  Meanwhile, your `LIKE` query finds any entries that contain the letter `c` anywhere, even if it's in the middle of a word.

Comment: Well, there's your problem: full-text search ignores words shorter than (by default) four letters.

Comment: Oh - four or more letters. How do I change that?

Comment: Did you know that the fancy blue words in posts like mine above are links?  Try clicking them!

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as count1 FROM blah WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST ('c') - returns 0 and ft_min_word_len has been changed to 1 and says 1 in SHOW VARIABLES

Comment: Hmm, did you rebuild the index?

Comment: I did REPAIR TABLE blah QUICK